# Add Control Elements to VrPanoramaView

Tags: android, virtual-reality, google-vr

Im using [VrPanoramaView](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/pano/VrPanoramaView)  to show 360° Panorama Images in my Android App.

Is it possible to add Elements like a Button to the PanoramaView and handle Actions when the User focusses it by looking at it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate further on what you want to achieve?

Is it something like point and click?

My first guess is that it is possible if you have access to the GLES capabilities on the phone, through the SDK. But further reading says:

> VR View that renders a static mono or stereo panorama (Experimental API).

So, probably the support for interaction still lacks refinement.